# How to import existing proprties of a Spring Boot application to AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store?

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud-aws, aws-parameter-store

When you want to migrate an existing Spring Boot application to AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store, is there a way to import all existing properties from the application's config file (application.yml) to AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store automatically?

I found there is a `aws ssm` cli available, which allows to put parameters to the Parameter Store, but it still seems, that I have to migrate each application property one by one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the documentation is concerned there is no reference of importing spring-boot parameters into SSM automatically. But you can use AWS CDK using Java language and bulk insert the parameters into SSM. Reading YML file in java is also trivial.

Reference of AWS CDK creating SSM Params is here
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/aws-ssm-readme.html#creating-new-ssm-parameters-in-your-cdk-app